# Code roadmap with css

Tags: html, css, dynamic

Can someone give me an idea or solution how to code roadmap like this https://managewp.com/about using css. I need it to be able to change dynamically when user puts in some new html code.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Download that page (HTML+CSS) and analyze how they did it.

OR

You can use Firebug in Firefox (or something similar in other browsers) to analyze it online. You can select HTML tag on page and you see what CSS was used for this tag. You can even modify CSS and see what will happend.
This way you will learn how to do it yourself.

Comment: Thanks, but this is just a background image on their site. I was thinking of drawing this dynamically.

Comment: With HTML+CSS you can do this without bitmap - see [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/tS43u/6/) (tested in Firefox, Chrome & Opera)

Comment: Another example on [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/tS43u/8/) and you can do what you want - without bitmap - I changed only CSS.